# Retrieving the "csv" file from /storage/emulated/ directory from Mac using Android File Transfer.app

Tags: internal-storage, storage, file-transfer

I'm using [Trepn Profiler](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/increase-app-performance/trepn-profiler) to profile the App's performance.

I can save session as `CSV` in `/stoarge/emulated/0/trepn` directory.

[image]

However, the issue is that I can't find the directory from my Android File Transfer.app.

[image]

What might be wrong? What tool enables me to access the directory?

Comment: some of the Programs, maybe set default Permission for this.can you give me this output in terminal at file directory ? command : `ls -la`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could use this script to pull the database files from Trepn.

```
output_dir=$@
#Get all of a directory(sdcard), and filter them
for file in `adb shell ls /sdcard/trepn/*.db`
do
    file=`echo -e $file | tr -d "\r\n"` 
    # pull the command
    adb pull $file $output_dir
    adb shell "rm $file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason why, but my Android File Transfer for Mac doesn't properly synced with the Android phone.

I had to open File Manage in Android, point to the file that I saved, and then I shared it with my google drive.

[image]

This works, but I think Android File Transfer should just show the saved file automatically.

Comment: it's better to take a picture of file permisions, this is i talking about.but for solved the problem, several ways availabe for find the better way.you maybe can change file permission(if it's not availabe for showing).

Comment: @Mohsen: I'm not sure how to show the file permission from Mac as Android is not mounted as a directory. For Android, the screen capture shows that it is -rw.